# Trying to understand how scripts should be added and in what order - experiencing difficulties

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hierarchy, src

I'm having some difficulties with what seems to be an issue with the order that I import the JS src.

I'm pretty new to JS / jQuery so for the most part have taken for granted that I only needed to include one script and all has been working fine.

I have a contact page, on the page there is a google map and form, the form also relies on som JS to pretty it up and to validate inputs.

These were working fine.

I've now just updated the login box that will be in the header, the dropdown uses a simple jquery function to display it when selected.

Now that I have this script in place I cannot get them all to work together, I've tried various combinations but none work so I must be missing something that's important, could someone please explain?

These are examples:

The map always displays and the login function is contained within the "helperFunctions" whilst the form function calls are within "ourContactForm"

1 : 
The form displays correctly, the login will not work

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/map.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> <!--Disable zoom to pinch-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="js/helperFunctions.js"></script>

<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jqtransform.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ourContactForm.js"></script>
```

2 :
Form doesn't display how it should yet the login does

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/map.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> <!--Disable zoom to pinch-->

<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="js/helperFunctions.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jqtransform.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ourContactForm.js"></script>
```

other permutations result is not a great deal of anything working.

Thanks for your help

EDIT:  using the details on jquery documentation solved :) 
http://jquery.com/download/

Comment: Are you including two different versions of jquery?! If so, why?

Comment: I think I was without realising.  So I guess they were overwriting each other?  This is from the jquery site : <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

I think i'll use those from now on and remove the others

Comment: Think there were 3 versions :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone stumbling across this that made the same dumb mistake...

These:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

taken from http://jquery.com/download/

will solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In both examples You include both jQuery 1.3.2 and the latest one. Why? I guess, that Your plugins work with other version of jQuery. Just check it and include only one.